# Truncated text on short select fields

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone had a solution for truncated text on short select fields.

Essentially I have a very narrow select box with a generous amount of padding. In Chrome (left) if your text does not fit inside the area before the menu button, your text is truncated.

In this instance this can be fixed by removing the right padding. However if I do this then I end up with the menu button being squished on the edge of the field in IE (I only really don't like this because it's ugly).

Does anyone have a solution that doesn't include a hack-y work around or alternate control?

It is just a vanilla select box with some padding on it.

[image]

Edit: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgA8K/2/

Example Html:

```
<select>
    <option>AM</option>
</select>
```

Example Css:

```
/** Pretend there is a CSS RESET here **/
select
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 13px;
    width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post an example of said code? If I could see the HTML and CSS I could give you a solution. Its hard to visualize a problem without seeing the code behind it.

Comment: There you go, jsFiddle and code.

Comment: Finally, to answer your question, I need one straight answer from you. Does the padding on the select have to be EXACTLY what it is? or do you mind a slight change in that?

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is is that you defined the select box to be exactly 70px wide. That means that the padding must obey the rule. In order for your padding to be 13px and the width to be 70px, it requires CSS to crush your actual select arrow into a smaller space to allow for both rules. I recommend changing your padding to 10px or making the box bigger.

Or what else you can do is change the font-size slightly to fit. For instance, in your `select` style, add `font-size:12px;` which should make the entire word visible and nice looking. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately the padding does need to be specific, I am looking for "creative" alternatives.

Comment: Ok Does the width have to be specific as well? @JamesMcDonnell

Comment: This is really the only width that fits in the parent contain with the other elements.

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell Alright, I've edited my answer. Hope this is what you were looking for.